# SSH Scp - can't specify local path where to copy files from server

Tags: ubuntu, scp, ubuntu-10.04, openssh

i'm trying to download .zip file from bluehost server to my computer. Like this -

scp username@domainname:/pathof/file.zip /home/Public/username/

I found out, when writing local address (where i want to put file) still refers to server address (pressing tab). What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) would be the correct place for this question. Alternatively you could try the [Linux/Unix stack exchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scp to copy from the computer you are on to the one you are ssh connected to. While ssh connected if you have ssh running on the host machine you are on and connected to the remote, from the remote you connect to the machine you are on as if it was remote. 
scp is not really a utility is it? it a process but one with a single clearly defined start and end so it looks like a utility command.

Answer (score 1):

The target location looks wrong. Shouldn't it be:

```
/home/username/Public
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing was .. that I was using SCP when i was SSH connected - in same shell. I thought that SCP is child command of SSH ...